# ASP MVC Membership can't display images when user is not loggedin

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have some images in content folder that I need to add to login page. Problem is that when user is logged in I ca show that image '#someDivId{ background: ../../Content/Image.png' but when user is not logged in I can't display that picture on login page. Any idea how to display that images if user is not logged in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your web.config probably needs something like this in it

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```